# Search hash results for similar matches rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, hash

I'm using the Facebook API to pull a list of all of my friends.   However, I don't want to store the results in the database. I just want to take the hash of results that I get back and perform selects on the results.

However, I'm having a hard time doing that...

I get results like this...

```
[{"name"=>"John Smith", "id"=>"12345"}, {"name"=>"Jane Doe", "id"=>"23456"}, {"name"=>"Samuel Jackson", "id"=>"34567"}, {"name"=>"Kate Upton", "id"=>"45678"}]
```

They're stored in @friends

My select is:

```
@friends.select{|key, hash| hash["name"] == "John Smith" }
```

but I keep getting an error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Two questions:
1.  How can I get the search of the hash to return John Smith (without storing in a database, and without modifying the initial Facebook API query)
2. Is it possible to use "Like" rather than "==" so that it returns results containing the word?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `"undefined method [] for nil:NilClass"` because you are using the method [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) wrongly.  Try doing this:

```
 @friends.select{ |hash| hash["name"] == "John Smith" }
```

So I believe this answers your first question. You don't need to store anything in the database, but in the instance variable `@friends`, and use select correctly.

Regarding the second question, I believe you should look into regular expressions, as it really depends on what do you mean by "like", but if you say that you want:

> it returns results containing the word?

Well, if you want to check for a specific word (let's say **Smith**), you would do the select as:

```
@friends.select{ |hash| hash["name"].include? "Smith" }
```

Which would give you all the elements on the array which **name** includes the word **Smith**.